# Flashing to SD Yocto image following solidrun tutorial

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yocto

I'm following these steps (https://github.com/SolidRun/meta-solidrun-arm-imx8) to build a Yocto image. I have built one, but on the last step, it doesn't work.

```
bunzip2 -c tmp/deploy/images/imx8mpsolidrun/core-image-minimal-imx8mpsolidrun.wic.bz2 | sudo dd of=/mnt/F bs=1M
dd: failed to open '/mnt/F': Is a directory
```

My SD is mounted on F and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 WSL. What is wrong? I have tried to decompress the file imx8mpsolidrun/core-image-minimal-imx8mpsolidrun.wic.bz2

but i get this:

bzip2: Input file tmp/deploy/images/imx8mpsolidrun/core-image-minimal-imx8mpsolidrun.wic.bz2 is not a normal file.

What is wrong here?

Thank you so much.

Comment: you must use the device name, not a folder where its fs is mounted, e.g. `/dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not following the tutorial.
dd command allow you to write in a file not a directory, "of" stands for *output file* https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html. Here you try to do it on a directory.

When you plug your usb device, a new file is created at /dev/. It is often /dev/sdX with X a letter. For instance /dev/sda or /dev/sda1.
Hence I suggest you to determine what is the file created when you plug your device.

```
# usb not mounted
sudo blkid
# usb mounted
sudo blkid
```

Then you will find your /dev/sdX. Afterwards type your command as suggested in the tutorial :

```
bunzip2 -c tmp/deploy/images/imx8mpsolidrun/imx-image-full-imx8mpsolidrun.wic.bz2 | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX bs=1M
```

Comment: You are right. But, anyway I can't do this from WSL. WSL doesn't have access to SD cards.